How to define the title and subtitle of mobile workflow tile
Microsoft decided to deprecate Office 365 connectors. We have to move to the new workflows as described here.
I succeeded in creating a card which is invoked by a webhook.
Current payload as described below.
In the screen below, you can see the old tiles (with the duck) on my mobile phone. I have highlighted the problematic text on the new ones in yellow. They only contain default text, which I want to override (the title translates as "Workflows published" and the subtitle is in English, "Card").

I am desperately searching for information how to define the yellow areas. In the yellow area I want to put some information but I don't get it.
{
    "attachments" : [
        {
            "content" : {
                "body" : [
                    {
                        "wrap" : true,
                        "text" : "...",
                        "weight" : "Bolder",
                        "horizontalAlignment" : "Left",
                        "spacing" : "Medium",
                        "color" : "Accent",
                        "id" : "Title",
                        "type" : "TextBlock",
                        "size" : "ExtraLarge"
                    },
                    {
                        "wrap" : true,
                        "separator" : true,
                        "id" : "acHeaderTagLine",
                        "type" : "TextBlock",
                        "text" : ".."
                    },
                    {
                        "wrap" : true,
                        "text" : "...",
                        "weight" : "Bolder",
                        "spacing" : "None",
                        "type" : "TextBlock",
                        "id" : "acHeader",
                        "size" : "ExtraLarge"
                    },
                    {
                        "type" : "TextBlock",
                        "text" : "..",
                        "id" : "acInstructions",
                        "wrap" : true
                    },
                    {
                        "type" : "TextBlock",
                        "text" : "..",
                        "wrap" : true
                    },
                    {
                        "facts" : [
                            {
                                "title" : "..",
                                "value" : ""
                            },
                            ....
                            {
                                "title" : "...",
                                "value" : ".."
                            }
                        ],
                        "type" : "FactSet"
                    }
                ],
                "version" : "1.4",
                "$schema" : "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
                "type" : "AdaptiveCard",
                "msteams" : {
                    "width" : "Full"
                }
            },
            "contentType" : "application/vnd.microsoft.card.adaptive",
            "contentUrl" : null
        }
    ],
    "type" : "message"
}


I tried to fix the broken links but the second one is missing. I hope you can see now how to add it.

hi @tripleee - thank you. I edited my post. The payload is in the lower section of the post.

Currently there is no way to change the preview for the messages (in the notification popup and Activity screen) sent via workflow. It will show as 'Card' which is by design.
